# Correlating function properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

Demo: https://tsplay.dev/WP9DJw

```
/**
 * Checks if the value of type string already exists in the data array
 * @param data
 * @param key
 * @param value
 * @param idKey
 * @param idValue
 * @returns true if the value exists in the data array
 */
function checkIfStringIsDuplicated<K extends PropertyKey, H extends PropertyKey = never>(
  data: Array<Partial<Record<K, string | null>> & Partial<Record<NoInfer<H>, string | number | null>>>,
  key: K,
  value: string,
  idKey?: H,
  idValue?: string | number | null
): boolean {
  return !!data.find((item) => {
    // If the value is found in the data array
    if (item[key] && item[key]?.trim().toLowerCase() === value.trim().toLowerCase()) {
      // Then check if the id of the value matches the found entry
      // If the ids are matching, then you are currently editing this exact entry
      // If the ids are NOT matching, then you have found a duplicate.
      if (idKey && item[idKey] && idValue) {
        if (typeof item[idKey] !== typeof idValue)
          throw new Error(
            `DuplicateValidationService: The type of ${item[idKey]} (${typeof item[idKey]}) doesn't match ${idValue} (${typeof idValue})`
          );
        return !(item[idKey] === idValue);
      } else {
        // If no idKey is provided or the item has no ID, then we have found a duplicate.
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Basic usage:

```
interface Car {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const dataArray: Array<Car> = [{id: 123, name: 'Tesla'}]

console.log(checkIfStringIsDuplicated(dataArray, 'name', 'Tesla', 'id', '123'))
```

So the function just checks if the same object properties exist in an array of objects. In addition to that you can pass the id of that object. Then the object with this exact id will ignore the property check, because we are editing this exact id.

Now the problem is, that the parameter `idKey`(PropertyKey) and `idValue`(real value) can have different types, but they shouldn't. That's why I have implemented this error message.

Is there a way to make the parameters depend on each other?

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVkDBm) what you are looking for?

Comment: Almost there. Is there also a way that I can additionally specificy an `idKey` matching the types `string|number|null` and the `idValue` `string|number`? Because I could pass `null` as `idValue ` when the key allows null

Comment: Exclude it: `idValue?: Exclude<T[H], null>`